# Issue with parsing IPA symbols with JSOUP

Tags: java, jsoup, html-parsing

I'm trying to parse English words transcptions from [www.wordreference.com](http://www.wordreference.com) with **jsoup**. But I have troubles with IPA symbols such as "æ", "ǝ", etc. Instead of these symbols I always get question marks. I tried different charsets but it doesn't work. Here is code:

```
public class TestClassParse {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Document doc;
        String transcription = "[ ]";
        try {

            String url = "http://www.wordreference.com/enru/word";
            String charset = "ISO-8859-1";

            doc = Jsoup.parse(new URL(url).openStream(), charset, url);
            Element transcriptionElement = doc.getElementById("pronWR");
            transcription = transcriptionElement.html();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println(transcription);
    }
}
```

The result of this code is **/w????d/**  instead of **/wɜːd/**. I used different charsets but get same results. How to get transcription in proper way?

Comment: What's the charset of the page? Apparently `UTF-8`. Why are you not using that? What's the idea of testing with different wrong charsets?

Comment: The charset is UTF-8. I used UTF-8, but still get question marks. I tried different charsets because got troubles whit UTF-8.

Comment: Why does the code have `String charset = "ISO-8859-1";`? Also make sure that you're displaying the results somewhere that is *capable* of displaying those characters.

Comment: Thank you for your comments! I've just tried to write result in a text file with UTF-8 encoding and everything works fine! It looks like IntelliJ IDEA output console doesn't display UTF-8 charset well.

Comment: Possibly you haven't configured IDEA properly.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Jsoup.connect()` to download the page. That will automatically use the charset value from the HTTP response and do the right thing.

```
String url = "http://www.wordreference.com/enru/word";

String transcription = "[ ]";
try {
    Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
    Element transcriptionElement = document.getElementById("pronWR");
    transcription = transcriptionElement.html();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

System.out.println(transcription);
```

Outputs `/wɜːd/`.